# What is the right way to express error in a custom Vault plugin

Tags: go, hashicorp-vault

I am working on [a custom Vault plugin](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/plugin) and I have a situation where if the input to an endpoint is invalid, I have to return an error. I know that in Go typically you'd have a function that returns a tuple `(retVal, error)` and if you like to return an error you would use the `error` part of the tuple.

In Vault, when you build an endpoint your return tuple would be `(*logical.Response, error)`. The thing here is that there is a function `logical.ErrorResponse(text string, ...)` that constructs a `logical.Response` with an error.

Therefore I am wondering, when I have an error, which of these variants is better to use:

Option 1:

```golang
if err != nil {
    return logical.ErrorResponse(err.Error()), nil
}
```

Option 2:

```golang
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

Option 3:

```golang
if err != nil {
    return logical.ErrorResponse(err.Error()), err
}
```

Comment: By the usage internally in the vault codebase seems that the `logical.ErrorResponse` is used for validation errors. Like an empty string which is required for a parameter. Check here https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/blob/master/vault/logical_system.go#L318

For the errors you need to use the typical go approach. `if err != nil { return nil, err }` https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/blob/master/vault/logical_system.go#L330

Comment: Thanks @SpirosI.Economakis; there is also a case where they use both: https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/blob/master/vault/logical_system.go#L362

Comment: In any case the best practice is to follow the go idiomatic, if there is an `err` then handle it and then use as Nima mentioned below the `logical.ErrorResponse` to see if there is an explanation of it.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, both of the usages are used inside of the vault codebase, I prefer using the golang approach, because if you use the first approach, you ave to chack that if all the `response != nil` , and if that wasn't then check the `response.Error!=nil`